firebase firestore finding document by date timestamp fails
From my app, I create a document with a field of type Timestamp where it is initialized as below:
 Date:Timestamp 
...
constructor(){
     const now = new Date()
     this.Date = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()));
   }

in the Firestore I see it stored as:
Date: October 7, 2024 at 12:00:00 AM UTC-5

In the Firebase function, however, when I try to search this document I get nothing. The code looks like below:
const now = new Date()
const ts:Timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()))
 const finColRef = db.collection("users/" + mapKey + "/finance")
      const fQuerySnapshot = await finColRef.where("Date", "==", ts).get()//
      fQuerySnapshot.forEach((doc:any) => {
        let data:any 
        data = doc.data()
        logger.log("fin data is::", data)
      });

This prints the server log like the below:
INFO 2024-10-08T05:06:06.189902Z Processing map user:HEkDmm3r3HggtDYIkzCOkLFjPpa2 uid:
INFO 2024-10-08T05:06:06.189877Z another timestamp to find data is: Timestamp { _seconds: 1728345600, _nanoseconds: 0 }

I am not sure what is the issue. If I use some other property like a number field then it works fine.


Are you sure that ts holds the same value as the Date field holds in the database? Can you please share a screenshot of your database?

I'm with Alex here: chances of having the exact same timestamp value when you call new Date() twice are very small. In fact, having a == check on Timestamp fields is quite uncommon too. It's more common to filter timestamp fields with > and < operations.

The value Date: October 7, 2024 at 12:00:00 AM UTC-5 is what I see in the database

@FrankvanPuffelen the time portion is stripped

Also as a business requirment, i need to copy the financial data every 24 hours in the firebase function for the user. To copy i need to find the most recent data which should be of the previous date. Time part does not matter just date. so happy to hear if there is a better way.

Firestore's timestamps use microsecond precision. So even if you call new Date() in code twice, one call after another, there will be a small difference between them, hence the behavior you see. Besides that, the == operator is commonly used to check the equality between numbers, not Date objects.
According to your last comment:

The time part does not matter just the date.

As also @FrankvanPuffelen already mentioned in his comment, the best option that you have is to use the > or < operators. In such a case, the query will not return documents with a perfect match but documents where the field Date holds a timestamp value that is greater or less than a specific date.

Thanks. So as I am dropping the time part why equal won’t work? also see my requirement in the last comment. Do you see a better way to do this?

That's because the microseconds still exist and are different. If you don't want to use a Firestore Timestamp due to these constraints, you might also consider using a Unix Timestamp, which is a long value. So your logic will work as long as the long numbers are equal.

Unix timestamp losses the timezone information of the user.  That create another set of problems. No way to drop microseconds the way I am dropping time?

Firestore timestamps don't have any timezones encoded into them either. The timezone of the Firestore timestamp is UTC. So you either create a timestamp that exactly matches those from the database, or you read a timestamp first from the database and perform a query right after that. Or as I already mentioned in my answer, you can use < or > operators.
